# Is there a way to avoid using the :not psuedo-class to pick an item out of a list in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Say I have an unordered list:

```
<div id="list">
<ul>
<li><a href="1.html">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="2.html"><img src="2.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="3.html">Item 3</a></li>
</div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
#list a:hover {background: #FFF;}
```

Is there an easy way to NOT target the img list item aside from using the :not psuedo-class. I'm sure there is but I'm having the hardest time figuring out what that is.

Thank you!

EDIT: Trying to avoid all psuedo-classes for IE7/8 support. :not and :nth-child are solutions to the problem, I'm just intentionally avoiding them.

Comment: No, there is not.  The only thing would be to assign classes to the `li` elements you DO want to address, and then modify your style selector: `#list li.bg-white a:hover {....}`.  Note - how would you do this with the `:not` pseudo class anyway?

Comment: What about using `:nth-child()` pseudo class?

Comment: I should have specified, I'm trying to do it without any psuedo-classes for IE7/8 support and without using JS or a similar work around.

Comment: @Dan you do know that `:hover` itself is psuedo code right?

Comment: Also, microsoft no-longer  supports ie10 and below (Just a little FYI)

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is, however it has support in IE7/8 unlike :not and :nth-child. Even if they don't support IE9 and below, people still use them (unfortunately.) I know the browser share for IE7 is a fraction of a percent too. The application I'm using this for however needed to function in IE7 without :not or :nth-child. It needed IE7+ support. Thank you though.

Comment: You can add using script but if you specifically need css, you can give different class name to a particular tag if you need IE7 support too

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child()` see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/dzx37chb/2/

`li:nth-child(odd) a:hover {background: blue;}`

Comment: Caveat: _It doesn't represent a general-case solution._

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to avoid all psuedo-classes for IE7/8 support, without adding JS but I thought of using nth-child. The list is actually longer than 3 items on the real deal but nth-child would still work.

Comment: @potashin I had to look up the definition of that one!

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: Excuse me?)

Comment: @potashin the word "Caveat"... I never heard of it before now, had to look it up :)

Comment: Why are you trying to support such an old browser? Please refer to this article https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support Mircosoft is *not* supporting anything under **IE 11**  as of January 12th, 2016

Comment: @BrentWhite lol, i just wrote the same thing in his comments below his question ;)

Answer (score -1):

An answer to my own question but please tell me if there is a better way:

```
<li class="selected-item"><a href="1.html">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="1.html">Item 1</a></li>
<li class="selected-item"><a href="1.html">Item 1</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.selected-item a:hover {background: #FFF;}
```

So just target the specific items. Its a bit clunky in the HTML.

Comment: Didn't your solution come from the first comment? and you didn't do it right

Comment: Could you explain what I didn't do right? I didn't get another solution so I rewrote it this way and it works fine. It just wasn't the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Your css class does not match the html class. `selected-item` vs `list-item`

Comment: Sure enough. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft has dropped support for anything under IE 11 as of January 12th, 2016.

Therefore it would be wise not waste your time on trying to find a solution for avoiding all psuedo-classes.

[Beginning January 12, 2016, only the most current version of Internet Explorer available for a supported operating system will receive technical supports and security updates.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support)

Comment: You are correct, however a lack of support does not mean that a) people no longer use IE7, 8, 9 and 10. Also that b) in this particular application, avoidance of :not and :nth-child was needed. This is a very specific question, otherwise I would very much agree with you.